# Условия if else и switch

Tags: c#

Возможно ли такое сделать с Switch ?

И может быть такие условия пишутся как то иначе если их много ?

```
if (a <= 5) {}
if else (a <= 10) {}
if else (a <= 15) {}
```

Comment: На правах магии: `switch ((a - 1) / 5)`. А вообще правильность решения зависит от задачи, которую вы решаете.

Comment: switch при большом колличестве case - заставляет компилятор строить jmp-таблицу. В IL-код таблица попадёт. Возможно после трансляции в машинный код таблица останется. Если вы очень уверены что jmp-таблица вам поможет - напишите 15-16 или более case-ов. Case обьеденяется так `case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: {} break;`